# How to use inner join with Spring MVC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hello I wrote inner join between the foreign key and the linked tables, but I can not print the data in the 2nd table. I get an error in Javascript, probably the data in the 2nd table is not coming there. I need user_name in User table but I can not access.

BookController

```
@Autowired
    private BooksService booksService;
    @Autowired
    private BookCommentsService bookCommentsService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/bookdetail")
    public ModelAndView showBookDetailForm(@RequestParam long book_id)
    {
        ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView("bookdetail");
        List<Books> book=booksService.bookGetWithId(book_id);
        List<BookComments> listBookComments= bookCommentsService.listAllDetailComments(book_id);
        mav.addObject("listBook",book);
        mav.addObject("listBookComments", listBookComments);
        return mav;
    }
```

BookCommentsService

```
@Service
public class BookCommentsService {
    @Autowired
    private BookCommentsRepository repository;
    
    public List<BookComments> listAllDetailComments(long book_id)
    {
        return repository.listAllDetailComments(book_id);
    }
}
```

BookCommentsRepository

```
public interface BookCommentsRepository extends CrudRepository<BookComments, Long> {
    @Query(value = "Select b From BookComments b inner join Users u on b.comment_user_id = u.user_id where b.comment_book_id= :book_id")
    public List<BookComments> listAllDetailComments(@Param("book_id") long book_id);    
}
```

BookDetail.js

```
<c:forEach items="${listBookComments}" var="bookcomments">  
       (No problem here)    ${bookcomments.book_comment}        
       (The error is here) <h4>${bookcomments.user_name}</h4>                        
                </c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use comment_user_id and close the braces, ${bookcomments.comment_user_id} should work fine.

Comment: Oh im sory copy paste problem. I change it but not working again. I can access bookcomments.comment_user_id but i need bookcomments.comment_user_name(user_name is in the Users table), BookComments table dont have user_name column, i use inner join but i cant access user_name in Users table.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you must use another *object* (known as a Data Transfer Object; DTO) which will contain the details from BookComments and the username.

An example would be:

```
package com.myapp.book;

public class BookCommentsDto{
    private String bookComment;
    private String username;
    // You can add any other attributes that you need from the table book_comments
    // add them in the constructor as well

    public BookCommentsDto(String bookComment, String username){
         this.bookComment = bookComment;
         this.username = username;
    }
}
```

I will refer to the class `BookCommentsDto` as dto. The above dto is the simple dto you might need. You can add other details you need from book comment in the dto and make sure to add them in the constructor as well. I have included a dummy package name on the top because we need to mention the full classpath of the dto in the query we will write. In the query below, I am creating the dto from the result of the sql. In the query, I am using the constructor of `BookCommentsDto` to create the object which will be returned.

```
@Query(value = "Select new com.myapp.book.BookCommentsDto(b.book_comment, u.user_name) From BookComments b inner join Users u on b.comment_user_id = u.user_id where b.comment_book_id= :book_id")
public List<BookCommentsDto> listAllDetailComments(@Param("book_id") long book_id);
```

Update return type in the service BookCommentsService

```
@Service
public class BookCommentsService {
    @Autowired
    private BookCommentsRepository repository;
    
    public List<BookCommentsDto> listAllDetailComments(long book_id)
    {
        return repository.listAllDetailComments(book_id);
    }
}
```

Update controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bookdetail")
    public ModelAndView showBookDetailForm(@RequestParam long book_id)
    {
        ModelAndView mav= new ModelAndView("bookdetail");
        List<Books> book=booksService.bookGetWithId(book_id);
        List<BookCommentsDto> listBookCommentsDto= bookCommentsService.listAllDetailComments(book_id);
        mav.addObject("listBook",book);
        mav.addObject("listBookCommentsDto", listBookCommentsDto);
        return mav;
    }
```

Finally update js

```
<c:forEach items="${listBookCommentsDto}" var="bookcommentsDto">  
       ${bookcommentsDto.bookComment}        
       <h4>${bookcommentsDto.username}</h4>                        
</c:forEach>
```

if you do the above changes, the code should work just fine.

I have a few comments for you if you want to improve your code and get better at coding.
When using Hibernate, we must think in terms of entities instead of tables found in the DB. Therefore we do not do inner joins like we do in native sql, instead we use hibernate relationship to define the relationship between the table and we join the **entities** instead of the tables. You can read on OneToMany, ManyToOne and ManyToMany relationships when it comes to joining entities.

`List<Books> book=booksService.bookGetWithId(book_id);`
A `book_id` is returning a list of `Books`? `book_id` should be unique per book if ids are used correctly and even if it is returning a list of books, the generic of the list should be `Book`, not `Books`; `List<Book>`, not `List<Books>`.

When hibernate is implemented correctly, you should be able to retrieve all the data at once and it would be something like:

This is the type of code is which you should be able to achieve after working with hibernate for a while (appx 1 year), however there is still a lot that can be improved about it.

In book's repository

```
@Query("from book b inner join b.comments c inner join c.users where b.book_id = :book_id")
Book getBook(@Param("book_id") long book_id); // bookService.getBook will call this method
```

Controller level

```
Book book = bookService.getBook(bookId); // only this one is querying the DB
List<BookComment> bookComments = book.getComments();
List<User> users = book.getComments().getUsers();
```

Advance topics to read on (read in same order as posted):

1. HQL - Hibernate Query Language
2. N+1 issue with Hibernate
3. JPA Specifications (for creating dynamic queries)
4. QueryDsl - an improvement of JPA Specifications

Comment: Thank you very much. I am very novice in Java, spring and hibernate. Editing code is really great, it was very useful for me. I took note of the list I should review, and I will review them in order and with care. Thank you very much again.

Comment: You are very welcome friend and I am glad I could help you. Happy coding :D